# Count comments of djangocms_comments in djangocms_blog

Tags: django, django-cms

how to get count number of comments of each post?

Inside each article I have comments and I want to display number of those comments on the parent list of all posts.

Ie.

```
li: 
  title: post 1
  comments: 12
li: 
  title: post 2
  comments: 32
```

etc..

I'm using 
[djangocms-comments](https://github.com/Nekmo/djangocms-comments)==0.2.2 and
[djangocms-blog](https://github.com/nephila/djangocms-blog)==0.8.1

Answer (score 1):

From the djangocms-comments documentation, it does not looks possible by using the stock code provided by djangocms-comments. A templatetag with code similar to https://github.com/Nekmo/djangocms-comments/blob/master/djangocms_comments/cms_plugins.py#L23 should do.

Create a `templatetags` package in any application installed in your peoject, then a module file (ex: `comments_tags.py`). In this file add:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.simple_tag(request_context=True)
def count_comments_for_post(context, post):
    obj = get_object_from_context(context)
    request = context['request']
    ct = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(obj)
    return self.get_comments(request, obj, ct).count()
```

load `comments_tags` in the blog template and something like `{% count_comments_for_post post %}` where you want the comments number for the post.

Note that code is untested as I did not use djangocms-comments, and can't currently verify it

Comment: Sorry, I'm noob.. Where I should add this code and what is it doing? I tried to add that on the bottom of cms_plugin (djangocms-commit) https://zapodaj.net/102fce3808b86.png.html, but it's return fails on '@register'.

Comment: It's hard to explain custom template tags in stack overflow comments :) You can probably check the django documentation on the topic: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#simple-tags

Comment: Ok then: 1) It's code for djangocms-comments? 2) it should be in cms_plugin.py? 3) Code with this function should be visible on djangocms placeholder, as plugin?

Comment: 1) "Create a templatetags package' you mean "http://docs.django-cms.org/en/release-3.3.x/introduction/plugins.html#create-a-new-polls-cms-integration-application"? 2) I need to create some fields on models.py? 3) "Invalid block tag: 'count_comments_for_post'"

Comment: See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#code-layout for an introduction to templatetags

Comment: Thanks, I will try it tomorrow and after that I will write some info ;)